# Running Oracle Forms inside Internet Explorer Browser

Tags: internet-explorer, oracleforms

I'm using Oracle Forms Builder 12.2.1.3.0 with Java Plug-in version 11.121.2 (JRE is 1.8.0_121).
First when I Installed the Oracle Fusion Middleware It said that the expected Java version is 1.8.0_131 but my version works too so I used it.
Now I try to run my Application but no luck, What I've tried so far:

- Java plug-in is enabled in the Internet Explorer.
- I added my localhost.home page in the Compatibility View Settings.
- I've played around the Internet Security Options ( Scripting of
  Java applets is enabled - change some Activex Controls and plug-ins
  options based on so many links when I googled my problem).

When I Run my application the sentence (ORACLE FORMS) appears then the browser asks me to install an Activex control, I Click install, then another window asks me if I want to let this program make changes, I Click yes, then the tab waits forever (waiting for localhost.home)
Internet Explorer Version is 11.706. 
What did I miss???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after I literally Tried everything to make my forms application runs with Internet Explorer 11, I came across a browser that its developers say that the browser will support Java Plug-in indefinitely, After trying tons of browsers It Finally works with this one. Its name is `Pale Moon`